# Increase size of image box under "featured products" in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, css

In home page , you can see Products under "SPECIAL" and "FEATURED PRODUCTS".

Featured products images are in a box , I wanted to increase the box size as like

"Products images which are under "special"."

To make clear, I want to increase the Product Images box size of "Featured products".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a custom theme, so you will need to find the correct file to modify by going to `System > Advanced > Developer` in the Magento admin and enable `Template Path Hints` under the `Debug` section. You will need to make sure `Current Configuration Scope` in the far upper left is set to the correct website (cannot be `Default Config`).

The file should be something like `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

In that file you should find a like that looks like `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135);`

Changing that number will resize your image. That line might appear a couple of times in the file (for list/grid), so make sure you change it in all locations. Also make sure you update the `width` and `height` if the `<img>` tag so the image doesn't get distorted.